# Is there a localStorage solution that auto expire old keys?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm storing the state of an application with localStorage, but store new keys for new products (I want to remember different products pages separated).

But as products will be renewed I need that old keys are removed after a week or a month. Is there a built solution for this?

I'm using Rails and jQuery.

Comment: No there's not, but it would be trivial to add a `created_at` or `expires_at` property to the data you store in `localStorage`.

Comment: Ok, but I'm very new to localStorage so it's not trivial to me... can you lead me in the right direction on how should I structure this data? I would like to store the id of the product, the expire_at with it, and have a list of configurations for this specific product (that expires when this product has not been visited for long time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see use [web-storage-cache](https://github.com/WQTeam/web-storage-cache). I have also had your problem before, I solved it by adding a property to save the expires time. Maybe you can try this web-storage-cache.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that are written, I didnt write this, but I like this one :

https://code.google.com/p/local-cache/

Works like a charm!